# Debugging (setting break point) Ilog Jrules in evaluation part

Tags: java, ilog, jrules, ibm-odm

I'm working with Jrules and ODM.
One of my evaluations fails due to a null pointer, and I want to know which particular condition failed.

How can I do this? The Jrules tutorials shows setting debug point in the action part, but not the evaluation (if...) part.
Is there a direct way to step condition by condition, so that I can locate which particular condition (evaluation) failed?

Comment: Tightened wording; rearranged phrasing for easier reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug in the actions by putting some print statements in the initialaction and finalaction of each rules.

```
initialaction{
System.err.println("Debug here"+variable);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add a sysout in the setter of the variable or loops used for actions and can see the system.out.log file inside sample server folder
(location: it depends in which drive we have installed the file)  to trace what see what value is passing through  that variable.
Thanks
Mohammed Khaleel